# angular 6 queryParamsHandling difference between merge and perserve

Tags: angular

In angular, What is the the difference between

`queryParamsHandling:"merge"` and `queryParamsHandling:"preserve"`?

Comment: https://alligator.io/angular/query-parameters/

Comment: this is only documentaion  of the query-parameters, it does not explain the difference

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you change the route from one url to another say from /firstUrl?name=bat7 to /secondUrl that time you need to say

```
this.router.navigate(['/secondUrl'], { queryParamsHandling: 'preserve' });
```

so that the queryParam "name" will not be lost

```
http://localhost:4200/secondUrl?name=bat7
```

and if you say merge like,

```
this.router.navigate(['/secondUrl/newVal'], { queryParams: { age: 'not-known'}, queryParamsHandling: 'merge' });
```

it would be like below

```
http://localhost:4200/secondUrl?name=bat7&age=not-known
```

The same query parameter can be taken to different routes and merged with needed params.

Comment: thanks! Can I use the merge also when I don't have any parameter?